# How to transfer .msi files to the client machines over the network from a .net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-installer

i would like to move set of dlls, exe and some .ini files to the client machines in an organization. For this I've created a .MSI file using WIX installer. This MSI actually moves the files to System32 folder in the client machine. This can be installed manually or through the Microsoft system center. But my client doesn't want to take any other product for this installation. So i have a piece of code which returns me the work stations with IPs. Can any one suggest me how this installation process can be automated using web application developed in csharp?
I've seen one **ManageEngine** http://www.manageengine.com/products/self-service-password/ product, In this product some how they are installing/uninstalling the exe/msi on the workstations from a web applications.

Answer (score 1):

This is what group policy deployment does. If there's a server with your MSI then use this kind of thing:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102

Note that this also solves a probable issue: installing those files in the system directory requires admin privilege. Group Policy allows elevated install even if the user is not an administrator.

If you were going to do this with code it might already be something that you'd install on every client anyway. It would access the server share and install it from there or download and install it. Same thing if it's a web server. You can't really push a file to each workstation unless you can access the admin share, and I suspect that trying to write code that does what Group Policy already does will be a more time consuming task than creating the setup MSI file.

Group Policy is how things like Microsoft Office get installed in corporate environments of thousands of workstations without having someone go around each one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in my case the Administrator will not take care of these installations more over installing/uninstalling our MSI will be happening everyday. So we thought of web solution where the Account operator can easily login and do this daily operations.

Comment: A reference to another product that does this changes nothing. If ManageEngine is worth selling as product then it's not just a few lines of code that somebody can tell you how to write. It makes no difference to the issue you have, which is that writing your own is a lot of work. By the way, Group Policy is not "another product" - it's a feature of Windows servers, so why can't they at least look at using it?

Comment: i know about Group policy, If the business users are much comfortable with the Group policy then why many companies put lot of efforts & work hours to build the same solution which is already there as a inbuilt service from Microsoft. BTW i'm not asking for the complete code for doing this but at least some sources from where i can have basic info to do this.